# After element not behaving correctly

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

For some reason, a piece of code of mine doesn't seem to work correctly. I've got a problem with only the after element. When hovering over the heading, two lines should draw from the top left corner, and the bottom right corner. As you might be able to see, both of them start off in the top left corner, but leave in the right corners.

The problem is that the code seems correct, but still it won't work the way it should

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3csx9qg/)

Note the differences between the before and after elements when hovered. When they are not hovered, they are position in the places where their line will leave the block.
When they are hovered, they are positioned on the opposite side.

```
h1:before{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

h1:hover:before{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

h1:after{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

h1:hover:after{
    bottom: 0;   /*not working*/
    right: 0;    /*not working*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from left: 0 to right: 0 also requires adding left: auto on hover otherwise the element will be left AND right 0

Comment: Thank you SO SO much! I completely forgot that it was an absolute positioned element. It all makes sense now